# En una consulta SELECT en PHP con una variable es '$grupopregun1' o '".$grupopregun1."' o '.$grupopregun1.'

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, select

En una consulta SELECT en php como la siguiente, en la que aparece una variable com se debe escribir la variable '$grupopregun1' o '".$grupopregun1."' o '.$grupopregun1.' ¿Existe alguna diferencia entre las 3?

```
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE grupo = '$grupopregun1' ORDER BY RAND()";
                  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($conn));
                  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                    $pregunta = $mostrar['preguntas'];
                    ?>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Puedes leer más sobre lo que necesitas en este [link de la documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: @gaidyjg no me ha quedado nada claro y creo que no resulve mi pregunta.

Comment: En realidad sí lo resuelve porque incluso dice los cómos y por qués del uso de las comillas simples y dobles y cómo funcionan las variables de PHP en cada una, pero eso ya es otra cosa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo depende de que estás buscando imprimir.
Acá la concatenación debe ser correcta siempre, independientemente como uses la variable. Por que terminará siendo usada en mysql.

Por ejemplo, la primera y segunda están correctas. Pero la tercera es un error de sintaxis.

```
string(59) "SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE grupo = 'uno' ORDER BY RAND()"
string(59) "SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE grupo = 'dos' ORDER BY RAND()"
string(62) "SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE grupo = '.tres.' ORDER BY RAND()"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. ¿Pero y el que sea una variable no tiene nada que ver? ¿No cambia nada?

Comment: La variable contiene datos, esos datos son aplicados a la sentencia. En este caso puedes ver como cargue `$grupopregun1` con los valores `"uno"`, `"dos"` y `"tres"`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Me sirvió.